# Is there a way manipulate the shaft power equation to show BHP as the area under the curve of Flow v. Pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, power

[image]
Pump curves are frequently presented in terms of Flow rate Q (typically x) vs Pressure Head H (typically y) and can have different shapes depending n the technology (centrifugal, turbine etc..) Given the shaft power equation P= Q*H*SG / Constant*Eff where Eff is efficiency (available from manufacturers but varies with Q) and SG= specific gravity. SG can essentially be considered constant with liquids but efficiency can not.

This leaves an equation in the form of y= k(x*z/w) where P= k (Q*H/Eff). The performance curves for Q v. H are typically simple linear or parabolic functions. It would seem practical to assume that the slope of one of these curves could be represented by dH/dQ = P (constant) if we assume efficiency is constant but here it is not.

Is there a way to approach this (or should this be presented in math exchange)?

Comment: Hi. What does 'QHSG' stand for?

Comment: Q*H*SG, Q=Flow Rate, H=differential pressure or Head developed , SG= specific gravity of the fluid

Comment: You're badly mixing *units of measurements* there. If $H$ is in $\mathrm{ft}$ then the SG ($\rho$) cannot be $1$.

Comment: Your question might be easier to answer if you could include a picture of a particular pump curve, and give details of what you are looking for with that particular pump curve.

Comment: Pump curve attached above (h vs. Q with Eff green, . Note that units have already been addressed with the use of 3960 and that SG is unitless. Consider the max size impeller, approx. 6" and the flow range 25-75 GPM. Assuming SG=1.0 then P(hp) = Q (h) / (3960)(η)  -  similar to work representing the area under the curve in a plot of pressure vs. volume, w= PdV except here with SG constant we have 4 variables instead of 3 and those are P and Q, h and Efficiency - we have reason to believe Power is reflected by the area under the Q vs h curve but with the efficiency being a variable, not sure?

Comment: In principle, it should be possible to do what you are wanting to do, if you develop equations for head as a function of flow rate and efficiency as a function of flow rate.  However, why would you want to do an integral when you can just read the power requirement directly off of the plot that you posted?

Comment: attached above is a standard pump curve - we also have a specialty pump where HP drops as Q increases. Speculating we can use area under the curve to explain this if I can get it into the proper format (where power is the area under the curve similar to  work and the p x V curve) but here we have the extra variable, efficiency (P on h x Q curve with varying Eff.)